# What is the history behind the development of the term "coefficient"?

Tags: terminology, math-history

Why are coefficients called "coefficients"?

For example I learned that squaring a number is called "squaring" because it actually refers to "making a square". That's how it was developed.

```
|<----+-----+---->|   3 

      squared


+-----+-----+-----+ 
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+ 
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+ 
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

So what is efficient about a coefficient and why is it a "co" like a "coworker" or "coauthor" or a "coeditor"? I feel like if I understood it's history I might remember what it refers to.

Comment: see http://prntscr.com/4fskyd

Comment: How is this not on topic. It's fully fits **"History and development of mathematics"**. The history of the term describes why it's called "coefficient" in the same way the history and development of "squaring" describes why it's called the "square" of a number. I edited it to make that clearer

Comment: This is what happens with idle people who don't know how to contribute constructively but want to desperately indulge in some activity for timepass. They had put my first question on  hold for a similar stupid reason. I love this site very much but really hate these mindless moderators >.<

Comment: I have voted to re-open, math.stackexchange.com seems quite resilient enough to support questions of math-history, which is after all an existing tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

com- from modern Latin meaning *together*.

efficient- also from modern Latin meaning *accomplishing*.

So it means to *cooperate to produce a result*.

Comment: really? That's it? That description fits every part of the an equation

Comment: There are manifold meanings of mathematical terminology, in variable contexts.

Comment: @gman the word *conjugate* literally means *yoked together* which could also be applied to any part of an equation. But it's not...

Comment: The word *coefficient* is used not only in the context of an equation, but whenever a "fixed" or predetermined quantity (the coefficient) is multiplied by a "variable" or not-yet determined quantity.

Answer (score 14):

The Oxford English Dictionary says:

> According to Hutton, Vieta, who died in 1603, and wrote in Latin, introduced coefficiens in this sense.

and general meaning of the word around that time seems to have been

> Cooperating to produce a result.

So perhaps the meaning is that the coefficient on $5 x$, namely the numeral $5$, cooperates with the value of $x$ to produce the result.